# Payroll software design using Microsoft Lightswitch

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-lightswitch, n-tier-architecture

we at our company are trying out some new technologies so thought of redesigning our legacy systems using Microsoft Lightswitch. Now my question to the community is whether this is a good choice in terms of performance, scalability, stability because currently our clients are running around 1000 employee payroll. Another thing we are worried about is, in our current system we have a custom formula builder system which is using a tree control and the users can create nodes and write formula based on the previous entries made on the tree, like if a user creates a `BASIC` node which is entered once(meaning that this value once entered does not change and is carried over to the next period until it is again changed by the user) and then he creates a `HRA` node with some formula like `BASIC*5%`, how should we think to implement this formula builder and lexical analyzer using lightswitch. We also have a ERP system(huge data systems, database size ranging from 10-15gb) which will be our next target if this one goes through with lightswitch.

Now I want some real insight about - are we on the right track and also if there is some better architectural design of Payroll system then please share, as it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might just be my perception, but I believe lightswitch has a more... "casual" intended audience. Personally, I would hope to use something a bit more robust there - my default would be full ASP.NET MVC with a proper back-end.

Simply: with payroll and big ERP, you probably want some serious/professional programming. You can probably do it inside lightswitch, but I worry you would be facing unnecessary battles.